# Python attr - Choice of 2 attributes

Tags: python, class, attributes, attr

I want to create a class that contains 2 attributes that are optional, but have 1 at least. I have tried the following, but this is not allowed by attr and it wouldn't ensure having at least 1 of them.

```py
@attr.s
class myClass():
    attrA = attr.ib(default=None, validator=optional(instance_of(int)))
    attrB = attr.ib(default=None, validator=optional(instance_of(int)))

# Desired behaviour 
>>> a = myClass(attrA=1)
>>> a.attrA
1
>>> a.attrB
None

>>> a = myClass(attrB=2)
>>> a.attrA
None
>>> a.attrB
1
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally sure what the code you showed tries to do, but in any case it is possible to achieve what you are asking by using a custom initialization method rather than the `attr.s` decorator:

```
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self, attrA=None, attrB=None):
       if not (attrA or attrB):
           raise ValueError('one of the attributes must be provided')
       self.attrA = attrA
       self.attrB = attrB
```